# value of the image clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to display 5 images one after the other. Let the **first image** value be **1**, **second be 2** and so on . How to assign the values to images and when any of the image is clicked how to assign the retrieved value in a variable and display the value of the clicked image in the **id="result_value"**

```
  <div class="images" id="images" >
    <img src="one.gif" class="one" alt="Number 1" width="42" height="42">
    <img src="two.gif" class="two" alt="Number 1" width="42" height="42">
    <img src="three.gif" class="three" alt="Number 1" width="42" height="42">
    <img src="four.gif" class="four" alt="Number 1" width="42" height="42">
    <img src="five.gif" class="five" alt="Number 1" width="42" height="42">
  </div>
  <div class="result_value" id="result_value" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#images img").click(function(){
        var va = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#result_value").text(va);
    });
});
```

see 

#### Fiddle Demo

Comment: You almost solved my problem, as I am new to web development can I know how to save this value in database using ajax

Comment: @user3671365, if that's what you need to know, then you should include that in your question. As it stands, your question doesn't mention *anything* about databases or AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-attribute of html5 see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data) tutorial.You can use jquery events in your case to make your job easy.
.Hope it helps

Comment: How to save this value in database using ajax and jquery?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery :

```
$('#images img').on('click',function(){
    $('#result_value').text($(this).index('#images img')+1);
});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 data attribute:

```
<img src="one.gif" data-image-n="1" class="one" alt="Number 1" width="42" height="42">
```

After you can get the number with jquery like that :

```
$('img').on('click',function(){
    var n = $('this').data('image-n');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following code to save this using ajax and jquery:

```
$.ajax({
            url :   "your-url-here",
            type    :   "POST",
            dataType:       "JSON",
            data    :   ({param1:1,param2:2,....}),
            success :   function(data){
                //actions based on response from server side script
                if(data['isValid']== "1"){

                }else if(data['isValid']== "0"){
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question that was asked in any way.